# C++| BST reference-to-node-pointer vs. a node-pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, binary-search-tree

Suppose I have this BST template:

```
template <typename T> class Node {
private:
public:
  T data;
  Node *left;
  Node *right;

  Node(T dt) : data{dt}, left{nullptr}, right{nullptr} {}
  ~Node() {
    this->data = 0;
    this->left = nullptr;
    this->right = nullptr;
  }
};

template <typename T> class BST {
private:
  Node<T> *_root;

  _insert();
  _add();
  _printOrder_In(Node<T> *parent, std::ostream& os) {
    if (!parent) return;
    _printOrder_In(parent->left, os);
    os << parent->data << ' ';
    _printOrder_In(parent->right, os);
  }

public:
  BST() : _root{nullptr} {}
  ~BST();
  
  insert();
  add();
  std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os = std::cout) {
    _printOder_In(this->_root, os);
    return os;
  }
};
```

Why do the following code work when I pass a reference-to-the-node-pointer, not work when I pass the-node-pointer?

```
// BST MEMBER FUNCTIONS:
private:
  void _insert(Node<T>* &parent, const T &val) { // works
//void _insert(Node<T>*  parent, const T &val) { // doesn't work, apparently generates nodes indefinitely
    if (!parent)
      parent = new Node<T>{val};
    else {
      if (val < parent->data)
        _insert(parent->left, val);
      else if (val > parent->data)
        _insert(parent->right, val);
      else
        return;
    }
  }

public:
  void insert(const T &val) {
    _insert(this->_root, val);
  }
};
```

Also as opposed to this alternate method, which simply works with the passed pointer:

```
// BST MEMBER FUNCTIONS:
private:
  void _add(Node<T>* parent, T val) {
    if (parent->data > val) {
      if (!parent->left) {
        parent->left = new Node<T>{val};
      } else {
        _add(parent->left, val);
      }
    } else {
      if (!parent->right) {
        parent->right = new Node<T>{val};
      } else {
        _add(parent->right, val);
      }
    }
  }

public:
  void add(T val) {
    if (this->_root) {
      this->_add(this->_root, val);
    } else {
      this->_root = new Node<T>(val);
    }
  }
```

---

I understand that a reference-to-the-point will give me direct access to the passed pointer. However, I am stuck at the difference between the two methods. In the second method, the local copy used in the controlflow still works despite the pointer itself not being passed as reference.

Comment: `//void _insert(Node<T>*  parent, const T &val) {` The pointer `parent` is assigned in your function - it gets the address of a `new Node`. If you provide the pointer `parent` by value (like in the excluded line) then this assignment is lost after leaving the function. Providing the pointer by reference assures that the "original" pointer (i.e. the pointer you call your function with) is assigned and the change becomes persistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OPs issue is about [call-by-value vs. call-by-reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy).

The language C (the “anchestor” of C++) provides exclusively call-by-value.
The missing call-by-reference can be mimed by using the address of a variable instead of the variable itself.
(Of course, the parameter of the resp. function has to become a pointer-to-type instead of the type itself.)

So, a pointer is passed-by-value but its value can be used to access something outside the scope of the function, and the modification (done at its original storage) will survive the return from that function.

When C++ evolved out of C, this principle has been taken over.
However, C++ added the call-by-reference like it is known from other comparable languages (e.g. Pascal).

A simple demonstration of call-by-value vs. call-by-reference:

```
#include <iostream>

void callByValue(int a)
{
  std::cout
    << "callByValue():\n"
    << "  a: " << a << '\n'
    << "  a = 123;\n";
  a = 123;
  std::cout
    << "  a: " << a << '\n';
}

void callByRef(int &a)
{
  std::cout
    << "callByRef():\n"
    << "  a: " << a << '\n'
    << "  a = 123;\n";
  a = 123;
  std::cout
    << "  a: " << a << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  int b = 0;
  std::cout << "b: " << b << '\n';
  callByValue(b);
  std::cout << "b: " << b << '\n';
  callByRef(b);
  std::cout << "b: " << b << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
b: 0
callByValue():
  a: 0
  a = 123;
  a: 123
b: 0
callByRef():
  a: 0
  a = 123;
  a: 123
b: 123
```

Explanation:

- The change of `a` has a local effect only in `callByValue()` because `a` is passed by value. (I.e. a copy of the argument is passed to the function.)
- The change of `a` modifies the passed argument in `callByRef()` because `a` is passed by reference.

Easy-peasy? Of course. But that's exactly the same if parameter type `int` of `a` is replaced by any other type – e.g. `Node*` or even `Node<T>*`.

I took out the relevant lines from OPs code:

```
  void _insert(Node<T>* &parent, const T &val) { // works
    if (!parent)
      parent = new Node<T>{val};
```

If the value of argument `parent` is a `nullptr` then the `parent` is assigned the address of a new created `Node<T>`. Thereby, the pointer (variable) passed by reference is modified. Hence, the modification persists after leaving the function `_insert()`.

The other alternative:

```
  void _insert(Node<T>*  parent, const T &val) { // doesn't work, apparently generates nodes indefinitely
    if (!parent)
      parent = new Node<T>{val};
```

If the value of argument `parent` is a `nullptr` then the `parent` is assigned the address of a new created `Node<T>`. Thereby, the pointer is passed by value. So, the (original) variable (which was used in the call) is not changed – and still contains the `nullptr` when the function is left.

Btw. According to this, the address of the created `Node<T>` gets lost.
(It's not stored anymore anywhere.)
However, the `Node<T>` instance still resides in their allocated memory – inaccessible until end of process – degraded to a piece of wasted memory.
This is an example how [memory-leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) may occur.

Please, don't confuse this fact with the other that the pointer itself “mimes” a pass-by-reference.
Modifications of the object (of type `Node<T>`) the pointer points to (if it's not `nullptr`) will become persistent.

Having a closer look onto `_add()` it appears that only the pointed object (of type `Node<T>`) is modified but never the pointer itself.
So, passing it by value is completely sufficient and fine.

But for the correct working of `_insert()`, modifications of `parent` itself have to become persistent as well.
Thus, only the first alternative works correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation. I just realized that in the passed-by-value version, a copy of the pointer is created and modified in the local scope, not the original pointer itself; this copy gets deleted once the function reaches closure. The `*` and `&` side by side confused me since it was my first time seeing it. Now it's cleared up.